# Subscribe to AppDomain.UnhandledException in xUnit in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I have a xUnit test project targeting .NET Core 2.1 and I want to catch all unhandled exceptions.

```
[Fact]
public static void Test()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += Domain_UnhandledException;

    string test = null;
    test.ToString();
}

private static void Domain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
}
```

I set a Breakpoint the in the `Domain_UnhandledException` event handler but this function is never called.

If I subscribe to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event in a separate .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library and make my NUnit test project call the faulty code throwing an Exception, I get the same result: `Domain_UnhandledException` is not called.

I also tried to create a new domain using `AppDomain.CreateDomain` but I get an error telling me this framework doesn't support creating additional domains.

How can I achieve that? My goal is to catch all unhandled exception in our Core .NET Standard project to log them all.

Thank you

Comment: Use of `[Fact]` indicates you are using xUnit and not NUnit. Please change the tag.

Comment: You're right thanks. Too many use of `NLog` recently